# Database insert Bootstrap datepicker & timepicker value wrong

Tags: mysql, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using `Bootstrap datepicker` in my application for the users to pick a date.

When I test it and pick the `30th Apr`, the value I get is `Thu Apr 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid)` - (I live in Denmark, if it should help). My problem is that the value that is saved in my database is `2015-04-29 22:00:00`, which is one day before the actual picked date.

I've tried to fix the problem by creating a service and trough that format the date before it get inserted into the database.

**Service**

```
app.service('formatDateService', ['$q', function ($q) {
    this.formatDateTime = function (date) {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = date.getDate();
        var hour = date.getHours();
        var minute = date.getMinutes();
        var second = date.getSeconds();

        if (month.toString().length == 1) {
            var month = '0' + month;
        }

        if (day.toString().length == 1) {
            var day = '0' + day;
        }

        if (hour.toString().length == 1) {
            var hour = '0' + hour;
        }

        if (minute.toString().length == 1) {
            var minute = '0' + minute;
        }

        if (second.toString().length == 1) {
            var second = '0' + second;
        }

        var dateTime = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
        return dateTime;
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('CourseCreateController', ['$http', '$scope','$sessionStorage','$log','Session','api','divisionService','competenceService', 'formatDateService','$filter',  function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage,$log, Session, api, divisionService, competenceService, formatDateService, $filter) {
    $scope.createCourse = function () {
        $scope.course.assignment_end = formatDateService.formatDateTime($scope.course.assignment_end);
        $scope.course.date = formatDateService.formatDateTime($scope.course.date);
        $scope.course.start_time = formatDateService.formatDateTime($scope.course.start_time);
        $scope.course.end_time = formatDateService.formatDateTime($scope.course.end_time);

        $http({url: api.getUrl('course', null),
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                course: $scope.course
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });
    };
```

And I have the same issue with `Bootstrap timepicker` which go back 2 hours.

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the timezone, but I really don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the code is running on localhost then check your time zone & set it in the code & also check the date format for db by default it saves date in `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: @Shashikumar Misal I discovered that even that it inserts the date wrong into the database, it displayed it afterwards correctly so I'm not gonna use any more time on that "issue", but thanks a lot for your time and quick response

Comment: it will be storing as UTC and rendering the correct date for your timezone.